# how can I popup a text area using JQuery (nor input neither in another window)?

Tags: jquery, html, popup, textarea, smoothing

I was looking for how to pop up a text area, but I only found input popups and "new window" popups, I want something like a text area that smoothly appears when you click on the button that launches the text area (probably JQuery), Can someone give me a tip or a simple example?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a Modal? Inside the modal, you could place a text area.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(function () {
 $("#trigger").click(function() {
        $(".text-hidden").toggleClass("text");
 });
});
```

```css
.text-hidden {
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: 0% 40%;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.text {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="trigger" type="button">CLICK ME</button>
<input type="text" class="text-hidden"></input>
```

You can edit in CSS the way you will hide text area. (opacity, scale, transform, visiblity, anything)

Comment: I started to learn HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript and JQuery a few weeks ago, so I'm still a little bit dumb, thank you for your answer, it really solved my problem!